# How do I display a popup informing a NSTextField can't be empty in cocoa ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I display a popup informing a NSTextField can't be empty in cocoa ?

If the user click apply and the NSTextField is empty a popup should appear saying the field can't be empty.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by @beryllium only tells part of the story.

In fact, to properly validate text field input in Cocoa you should be using an `NSFormatter` attached to your text field cell and then in your `NSTextFieldDelegate` you should implement the method: `control:didFailToFormatString:errorDescription:`. In this delegate method you can prompt the user to correct their input.

All you need to do in your `NSFormatter` subclass is something like this:

```
@implementation RKTextFormatter

- (NSString*)stringForObjectValue:(id)object 
{
    return (NSString*)object;
}

- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(id*)object forString:(NSString*)string errorDescription:(NSString**)error {

    BOOL stringPassesTest = NO;

    //put your test here 

    if(!stringPassesTest)
    {
        //set the error and return NO
        if(error)
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YourErrorDomain" code:1 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"It's a bingo" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
        return NO;
    }

    //otherwise, just assign the string
    *object = string;
    return YES;
}
@end
```

You would assign the formatter to your text field like so:

```
RKTextFormatter* formatter = [[RKTextFormatter alloc] init];
[[textField cell] setFormatter:formatter];
```

And then in your `NSTextFieldDelegate` you handle any invalid input:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control didFailToFormatString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString *)error
{
//display an alert, obviously it would be more useful than this
NSAlert* alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"You have failed me for the last time" defaultButton:@"Revise Input" alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@",error];

[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:control.window modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];

//if you return NO here, the user's input will not be accepted
//and the field will remain in focus
return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after few days I came back to your solution. I still have one question, beside my custom alert, another popup is shown. How can I suppress it ? (I've tried to remove the NSError line but it is still there.

Answer (score 5):

> If the user click apply and the NSTextField is empty a popup should
>   appear saying the field can't be empty.

Please, please, do not do this. You can be smarter than that.

Instead of investing your time in writing an alert dialog to handle the "unexpected" situation, invest it in creating a method that prevents the problem from occurring in the first place: **keep the `Apply` button disabled until a proper value has been entered in the text field**.

In addition, as `@Rob Keniger` mentioned, you should consider using `NSFormatter`s to validate the input to make sure it's of the appropriate kind.

Comment: And what if your form requires more than "is set"? This doesn't handle that case.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "form requires more than "is set"".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
- (IBAction)pushBtn:(id)sender {

    if(self.textfield.stringValue.length == 0){
        NSAlert * alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Error"
                                          defaultButton:@"OK"
                                        alternateButton:nil
                                            otherButton:nil
                              informativeTextWithFormat:@"Enter a text into text field"];

        [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window
                          modalDelegate:self
                         didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidHidden:)
                            contextInfo:nil]; 
        //[alert runModal]; - more simple way
    }
}

-(void)alertDidHidden:(NSAlert *)alert{

}
```